# Location of bulk and edges for Gaussian random matrices

Tags: random-matrices, eigenvalues

I have some trouble to understand the difference between the "bulk" and the "edges" of the spectral density of random matrices (for instance in this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/169178/random-matrices-why-to-distingusish-bulk-and-edge-cases)).

From my understanding, all properties of random matrices eigenvalues are actually only valid in the bulk (correlations for instance). But where does the separation begin ?

Let's take the example of Gaussian matrices. For instance, for 8x8 or 100x100 random matrices from the GOE, the spectral density looks like:

[image]

I initially thought "the bulk" designated for these matrices the inner part of the Wigner semi-circle, while the edges were the outer parts. Is such a crude guess a valid approximation (for practical applications for instance) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is important to distinguish results that apply only in the limit of a large matrix size $N$, from results that apply for small $N$ as well. The theory of random matrices addresses both large-$N$ properties as well as small-$N$ properties, and there are physical applications in both regimes.

I understand from your question that your interest is in large-$N$ properties of the GOE. Then "bulk" versus edge refers to the support $(-W,W)$ of the [Wigner semicircle,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_semicircle_distribution) rescaled such that $W={\cal O}(1)$. The transition from bulk to edge region is at a separation of order $N^{-2/3}$ from $\pm W$. The deviation of the eigenvalue density from the Wigner semicircle in the edge region is described by the [Tracy-Widom law.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracy%E2%80%93Widom_distribution)

But do keep in mind that the theory of random matrices is not restricted to the large-$N$ regime. For example, chaotic scattering from a billiard with an $N\times N$ transmission matrix is described by the circular ensembles for any $N$, even as small as $N=1,2,3,\ldots$. In that case there is no notion of bulk versus edge, but there are universal properties that can be measured in experiments, such as the $T^{-1/2}(1-T)^{-1/2}$ distribution of the transmission probability $T\in(0,1)$ for $N=1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this useful answer! For simulations, is there any investigation which have been conducted to know when the "large N limit" begins? I guess it depends on the applucation.

Comment: yes, it depends on the application; for many applications I am familiar with the correction to the large-$N$ result is a factor $1/N$ smaller.